# can multiple couninitialize calls crash an application ?

Tags: delphi

I have an application where i have created a thread which must check the database for a specific type of data for a timeout interval. The thread is fully responsible for creating the database connection, query and closing the connection. I make the CoInitialize call only once , in the thread execution and i reused the Ado connection and Ado Query for subsequent use .

Now my question is , I had previously ( perhaps erroneously) left a CoUnitialize statement in the loop for database data checking. which means , that the call to CoUnitialize was done every time . Why did the application did not crash ? As there was no data to release CoUnitialize should have failed. I am doubtful on this .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Pretty hard to reason about how an API should behave when you misuse it. Since `CoUninitialize` has no mechanism to report failure, it can't actually fail. Why did your app not crash? Perhaps `CoUninitialize` is robust to this misuse. No matter what, fix your app and move on.

Comment: I had the same question, I one of my apps, when I have a second call to CoInitialize the app frozen.

Comment: I did , actually. Now i have a counitialize call only when my thread is terminated. this will ensure only one ( Coinit - coUninit) pair

Comment: @CesarRomero : you cannot do that , two coinit calls without the first one releasing the resources WILL crash your app. Release by CoUninit , then reuse

Comment: It should crash. Are you sure you have called CoUnitialize each time? a very good article about this :http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benkuhn/archive/2006/09/15/756401.aspx

Comment: @RBA : Perphaps , it would have , under intensive tests. Maybe it was failing , since i have no way of knowing ( no return value).  either way , I have changed my code now to eliminate the chances

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CoUninitialize` is a WinApi function that takes nothing and returns nothing. Since those WINAPI functions never throw an exception (AFAIK), your application will not crash by calling them. `CoUnitialize` will just silently fail when called too many times.

Your application could crash afterwards though, when code is called that needs an initialized COM. That your application does not crash can mean two things: the code doesn't need `CoInitialize`, or somewhere else `CoInitialize` is called, maybe in your ADO library.